# Rejection Sampling in Poincaré disk - mapping a pdf to the tangent space

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, manifolds, sampling

I want to map the pdf of the  Normal distribution given in [Pennec](https://https:/hal.inria.fr/inria-00614994/document) to its tangent space, given mean $\overline x$ and precision matrix $\Gamma$. The Normal law on a manifold $\mathcal M$ is given as $$N_{(\overline{x}, \Gamma)}(y) = k \exp{((-\overrightarrow{\overline{x}y}^T \Gamma  \overrightarrow{\overline{x}y}})/2)$$

I have taken the mean to be $0$ and the precision matrix to be the identity matrix. In order to transform the pdf to it's tangent space, I use equation in Sec 3.3 (expression of density in a chart):
$$\rho_{x}(y) = p_{\mathrm x}(y) \sqrt{\det (G(y))}$$
where $\rho$ is the density in a chart $x = \pi(x)$, $G$ is the Riemannian metric, and $p$ would be the pdf on the manifold, i.e., $N_{(\overline x, \Gamma)}(y)$.

My **confusion comes up here**: Do I use $\exp (y)$ (the exponential mapping, not $e$) *instead of* $y$ in the volume form part of the second equation)? If so, I get the following explicit form of the Normal distribution (given mean $0$, precision matrix as identity) in terms of the usual coordinate chart in $2$ dimensions:

$$f(y) = k.e^{-0.5 ||y||^2} \cdot \frac{4}{(1 - \tanh^2{||y||})^2} $$

and the plot looks as follows (plotted via GeoGebra, taking $k=1$ for simplicity):

[image]

And this plot baffles me because I'm not sure what distribution to use for this in $\mathbb R^2$ to perform Rejection Sampling on it.